# How to set xData as date (Y-M) for Highcharts synchronized charts?

Tags: php, highcharts

I want to plot the synchronized charts like this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts. 
The JSON data will come from SQL database and the xData (x-axis) looks like below which are in **year-month** format:

```
xData: [
  "2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04",
  "2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2012-08","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04",  
  "2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04",  
  "2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2013-12","2004-04","2004-04",  
  "2007-11","2007-11","2012-08","2005-05","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04",  
  "2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2016-04","2004-04","2012-08","2004-04","2004-04",  
  "2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2005-05","2004-04","2004-04",
  "2012-08","2016-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2012-08","2004-04",  
  "2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2012-08","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04",
  "2004-04","2006-02","2007-11","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2005-05","2004-04",
  "2004-04","2005-05","2004-04","2004-04","2012-08","2012-08","2006-02","2005-05",
  "2004-04","2016-04","2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2006-02","2004-04","2004-04",
  "2004-04","2004-04","2004-04","2005-05","2007-11"
 ]
```

So, how to plot those data as x-axis for synchronized charts?

Comment: It's confusing a bit, because i can't imagine how would you like to present your data? Do you want to have the `n` number of points with the same values as axis ticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply use that one array as the labels for the xAxis:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: '{value}'
    }
},
```

but in order to plot on a timeline axis, you may need to convert these strings into integer values, which can be done with PHP: `strtotime($date.'-01 00:00:00')` ...hint: you need to multiply the result (in seconds) with `1000` for JavaScript timestamps (in milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

I added categories: "activity.xData" to to the chart
and set the labels format to "this.value"

```
xAxis: {
    crosshair: true,
    categories: activity.xData,
    events: {
        setExtremes: syncExtremes
    },
    labels: {
        format: this.value
    }
},
```